# Usage of effectively final variable

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have simple class that contains inner class that according to my understanding uses effectively final variable `f`:

```
public class WithInner {

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        WithInner i = new WithInner();
    }

    interface LocalInterface
    {
        void iia();
    }

    public void aa()
    {
        int f = 20;
        LocalInterface i = new LocalInterface() {
            public void iia() {
                System.out.println(" "+f);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

But my `Intellij` IDE complains regarding f is not declared final:

> local variable `f` is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared `final`

But if the `f` variable is effectively final there is no need to declare it `final`, isn't that true?

UPD:

My project structure is configured to use Java 8:

[image]

Comment: You need to make sure that your project is configure to use Java 8+ (under File - Project Structure)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408109/java-stopped-erroring-on-non-final-variables-in-inner-classes-java-8

Comment: Which Java Version do you usw?

Comment: I couldn't find one, so I did a CW answer on this for future use.

Comment: I didn't find one before because I was looking for [tag:eclipse], not [tag:intellij-idea]. Doh!

Comment: My project is configured to use Java 8. More details in UPD