# Change property attribute object of an final object

Tags: java, final

Argument of an method is final object. Why?

Does it means that in this method (service) this object (response) is like final class (You cannot override methods of that class /HttpServletResponse/ in this object /response/)?

Or it means that in this scope (inside this method /service/) You can't change reference of that argument object (response) to another, let say new, HttpServletResponse instance (in that scope)?

Like:

```
response = new HttpServletResponse();
```

Here is a code example:

```
public class ServletLifeCycleExample extends HttpServlet {

    private int count;
...
    @Override
    protected void service(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        getServletContext().log("service() called");
        count++;
        response.getWriter().write("Incrementing the count to " + count);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean why final method argument is used?

Comment: See this if it satisfies your quest. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162531/making-java-method-arguments-as-final

Comment: Yes, what is meaning to use final method argument.

Comment: @ShafinMahmud why You give me -1?

Comment: its not me bro :| I just tried to clearify your asking, I find no reason to give a -1. You have certain point of your query.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said `final` indicates that you can't change the reference to something else.

**i.e.**

```
response = new HttpServletResponse();
```

or

```
response = null;
```

are *prohibited*.

But you can change the attributes of `response` object

**i.e.** something like

```
response.setStatus(status)
```

would be *allowed*.

Comment: As I thought, just...Didn't think about null. Why I can't change it to null? (Add that to answer pls)

Comment: @zelenooq assigning to `null` would come under changing reference and we can't do that to `final` variables.